# Storyboard: align button in custom UIView to another button in parent UIView using auto-layout constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

Assume a custom UIView, CustomView, that is designed with a Xib file. Inside CustomView is a UIButton, CustomButton.

ParentView is a UIView that contains CustomView.

With Storyboard, is it possible to create an auto-layout constraint that center aligns CustomButton with another button in ParentView?

Comment: can you upload image like which type of scenario you want with auto layout ?

Comment: Maybe a simpler way of asking the question: how do you get the subviews of a custom UIView to appear in the Document Outline?

Comment: What about uibutton ? Image is easy way to understand the layout.

Comment: Is your CustomView in a separate Xib file and the UIView (parentView) in a  storyboard as part of a view controller scene? If they are in different files then its a bit difficult but if you can exactly tell where all these views reside it will be easier to provide an answer. If they are in the same file and the custom view is inside a UIView which is part of a view controller scene then its straight forward just like how you would use auto layout normally. Also is is center aligned vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @PradeepK thanks for the answer. Yes, they reside in separate files since the custom UIView is designed with a Xib file. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't do that as custom button don't know who is its super's super.In another words,not all of ParentView class have a CustomButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible to do what you are trying to do in storyboard. You would have to do it programatically.